# Access Dictionary<int,string> value from FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Asp.Net MVC 4 C#

I want to use dictionary type
so, on first page load in controller I tried this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
{
    dictionary.Add(i, "blue");
} 

ViewBag.Colour = dictionary;
```

And in View I am passing it back through Hidden field

```
@Html.Hidden("Colour", (Dictionary<int,string>)@ViewBag.Colour)
```

Now on `[HttpPost]` I want to access all the values (Key,Value) from `collection["Colour"]` and may be update the Value part on some condition.

Comment: Here's a possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385286/html-hiddenfor-does-not-work-on-lists-in-asp-net-mvc

Basically, Hidden field can only hold a string. You can either serialize your dictionary (and deserialize when it comes back), or put it into ViewBag, or cache on the server.

Comment: Please, show the code of your get and post Actions from your controller.

Comment: I have put the entire dictionary in a session and managed to retrieve it on postback... thank you.