# input type="hidden" asp-for= does not work for List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm looking for a smart way to store the values of a List in a `hidden input` in a form and getting the value back in my viewmodel when the form is posted.

In my viewmodel I have a list with `SelectListItem` items. The list is used as `asp-items` in a `select` element. Now when the user has turned off scrips and posts the form with errors, I want to re-show the form without having to recreate the list.

Property looks like:

```cs
public IReadOnlyCollection<SelectListItem> UserLevels { get; set; }
```

In the razor view this will not save the values of UserLevels correctly:

```html
<input type="hidden" asp-for="UserLevels"/>
```

I found [this question about a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385286/html-hiddenfor-does-not-work-on-lists-in-asp-net-mvc), but I didn't find a nice solution there. Does anybody know a smart way to store the values of the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searching and experimenting I figured out a nice solution.

I created two extension methods `SerializeForHidden` and `DeserializeForHidden` (see below) and added an extra property in the view model:

```cs
public string UserLevelsHidden
{
    get => UserLevels.SerializeForHidden();
    set => UserLevels = value.DeserializeForHidden(UserLevels);
}
```

Now the values of `UserLevels` are saved in the form and re-created at the post with:

```html
<input type="hidden" asp-for="UserLevelsHidden"/>
```

This will work for any serializable type, not just for Lists.

Extension methods:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web;

namespace Forestbrook.Web
{
    public static class WebHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize a value from a hidden HTML Form field which was serialized
        /// with SerializeForHidden to its original type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type to deserialize to</typeparam>
        /// <param name="value">serialized and HtmlEncoded string from HTML form</param>
        /// <param name="_">Target property only used to simplify detection of T. May be null.</param>
        /// <returns>Deserialized object or null when value was null or empty</returns>
        public static T DeserializeForHidden<T>(this string value, T _)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return default;

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize a complex value (like a List) to be stored in a hidden HTML Form field
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value to serialize</param>
        /// <returns>Json serialized and HtmlEncoded string</returns>
        public static string SerializeForHidden(this object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value,
                new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore }));
        }
    }
}
```

Mind that the `T _` parameter in DeserializeForHidden is only added to make the use of DeserializeForHidden easier. You can remove it if you like, but then you always have to specify the type.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do what is proposed in the answer you linked to.

Instead of trying to hide a list in one input, use one input for each element of the list.

It will be something like this

```
@for(int i = 0; i < UserLevels.Count(); i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserLevels[i]"/>
}
```

Comment: This will work for a list of strings, but not for a list with SelectListItem items. It renders like this:

<input type="hidden" id="UserLevels_0_" name="UserLevels[0]" value="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem" />

Comment: It also works for ints - worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add value property add assign it through the Model.
Try the below code:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="UserLevels" value="@Model.UserLevels" />
```