# Is there any way to store whole List using Tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to store a List in any tag using ASP tag helper. I am using that list to populate dropdown but also i need list data back in my post request. I tried `<input type='hidden'>` for it but it didnt work.

can anyone please suggest me how can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to put the data between a start tag and an end tag.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp

Comment: See this link if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627155/input-type-hidden-asp-for-does-not-work-for-list

Comment: @jdweng I guess you understand wrong but the answer given by 'SoftwareDveloper' is I wanted.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper Thanks for the suggestion. I got what I wanted.